# The MailChimp PHP library is missing the required GuzzleHttp library

Tags: drupal, mailchimp, guzzle

I have installed Guzzle on my Godaddy shared hosting via SSH but my Drupal site is still telling me that:

> "The MailChimp PHP library is missing the required GuzzleHttp library.
>   Please check the installation notes in README.txt."

Any ideas why it would be saying that? it appears to have installed correctly.

```
godaddy@user [~/public_html]$ php composer.phar require guzzlehttp/guzzle:~6.0
./composer.json has been created
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing guzzlehttp/promises (1.2.0)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing psr/http-message (1.0)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing guzzlehttp/psr7 (1.3.0)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (6.2.0)
    Downloading: 100%         

Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

Answer (score 1):

On the library page, if you are using the package https://github.com/thinkshout/mailchimp-api-php/releases which contains everything e.g. v1.0.6-package.zip (and therefore having everything already doesn't require composer to get them), then remove /vendor from .gitignore so that all the files in /vendor - including guzzle are included in your code base so that should you deploy the code from your repo to a production server, all of it will be loaded.

CREDIT: https://www.drupal.org/node/2709615#comment-11888769

Comment: The .gitignore is exactly what I had missed. Didn't notice the vendor folder missing in my live directory. Thanks!

Comment: +1 pleased it worked for you @CJdriver A further tip: once this solution is in place you may need to clear the Drupal cache at least once for the error message to go away. Clearing the cache via the admin pages of the website, via: admin/config/development/performance only required once. However, in local development environment when using drush, i.e. `drush cc all`, this was required more than once for my particular site. It may not be for yours but just to let you know of the possibility in case you think the solution hadn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the issue, Guzzle needed to be installed into the MailChimp libraries folder?! [Guzzle Instructions](https://www.drupal.org/node/2709615#comment-11116437)

```
godaddy@user [~/public_html]$ cd sites/all/libraries/mailchimp/
godaddy@user [~/public_html/sites/all/libraries/mailchimp]$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
All settings correct for using Composer
Downloading 1.1.1...

Composer successfully installed to: /home/mysite/public_html/sites/all/libraries/mailchimp/composer.phar
Use it: php composer.phar
godaddy@user [~/public_html/sites/all/libraries/mailchimp]$ ./composer.phar install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing sebastian/version (1.0.6)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing sebastian/global-state (1.1.1)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing sebastian/recursion-context (1.0.2)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing sebastian/exporter (1.2.1)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing sebastian/environment (1.3.7)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing sebastian/diff (1.4.1)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing sebastian/comparator (1.2.0)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing symfony/yaml (v3.0.6)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing doctrine/instantiator (1.0.5)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock (2.0.4)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing phpspec/prophecy (v1.6.0)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing phpunit/php-text-template (1.2.1)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects (2.3.8)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing phpunit/php-timer (1.0.8)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing phpunit/php-token-stream (1.4.8)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing phpunit/php-file-iterator (1.4.1)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing phpunit/php-code-coverage (2.2.4)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing phpunit/phpunit (4.8.21)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing guzzlehttp/promises (1.2.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing psr/http-message (1.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing guzzlehttp/psr7 (1.3.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (6.2.0)
    Loading from cache

sebastian/global-state suggests installing ext-uopz (*)
phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock suggests installing dflydev/markdown (~1.0)
phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock suggests installing erusev/parsedown (~1.0)
phpunit/php-code-coverage suggests installing ext-xdebug (>=2.2.1)
phpunit/phpunit suggests installing phpunit/php-invoker (~1.1)
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

Comment: Be aware that that library has not yet been updated to API v3.0, so it may not continue to work when MailChimp [sunsets older versions](https://devs.mailchimp.com/blog/sunsetting-previous-mailchimp-api-versions/) at the end of 2016.